# Best export settings for still image with audio

Tags: premiere, editing, encoding, adobe-media-encoder

Suppose I have a sequence in Premiere which is an audio track accompanied by a single still non-moving image (e.g. a song and the album art).

Being that there is no video (or motion of any kind), what would be the most efficient settings in Adobe Media Encoder to use to export this file for upload to YouTube? When you use the regular YouTube 1080p setting, the files are definitely too big.

The audio track itself was created in Premiere, so it would be more convenient to encode everything from the same place

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/18147/

Answer (score 1):

To minimise the file size for distribution of something like this, you need a Variable Frame Rate encoder, which will effectively just encode 1 frame, and set the frame rate such that there's no further frames. I've not seen this available in Adobe (or any commercial product I've looked into), but definitely there are services I've seen encoding video this way - I've seen examples of very small Facebook video files that appear to be VFR and done this way. In the absence of finding an available encoder, I'd just lower the bitrate as much as you can in Adobe that the image is still good, and use that. The upload time to YouTube might suck, but it only has to be uploaded once anyway.

If anyone does know of an available VFR (Variable Frame Rate) encoder, please post the info - this isn't the first time I've seen the question asked, but I'm yet to learn of any end-user available encoders to do this.

Comment: You can use the [Voukoder](https://www.voukoder.org/) plugin which allows one to encode directly using ffmpeg from within popular NLEs. You can then use x264 or x265..etc. Of course, you still have to set params like scenecut and keyint to control keyframe intervals.